# Rename Sharepoint Server 2010 including the update of paths and sites

Tags: sharepoint, rename

I'm currently working on renaming Sharepoint Server 2010. I managed to rename the Sharepoint Server, however my paths and sites that are linked to the old server name is down. 
May I know if there is any alternatives to rename the Sharepoint server that  will automatically update the names to the paths and sites that would not cause any broken links?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming a server could be a tough task. You should never run SharePoint sites using the server name, that is why host headers exist.

You need to run this command:
stsadm -o renameserver -oldservername [oldname] -newservername [newname]

Then you need to create Alternate Access Mappings:
stsadm -o addalternatedomain -url [oldurl] -urlzone intranet –incoming url [newurl]

Of course, you can use the PowerShell equivalent.